# How can I sort a second array based on a first array which was sorted with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, sorting, nspredicate

I have two `NSMutableArrays`: `searchResults` and `searchResultsDetails`. I sort searchResults with `NSPredicate`, and I want `searchResultsDetails` to be sorted based on which objects were removed from `searchResults` with the `NSPredicate`.

For example, let's say searchResults originally contains 1,2,3,4,5 and `searchResultsDetails` originally contains A,B,C,D,E. So after sorting it with `NSPredicate`, searchResults contains 1,2,5, and I want `searchResultsDetails` to contain A,B,E. How can I accomplish this?

This is the code I am using to sort the first array.

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS %@",
                                searchText];

self.searchResults = [self.lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Comment: Instead of two separate arrays for the "lines" and the "details", you better but all information together in one array of dictionaries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887505/wrong-cells-value-in-tableview-after-searching for a similar problem and a possible solution.

Comment: Btw: You *filter* (not *sort*) with a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ashu",@"toremove",@"ashuabc",@"toremove",@"ashu12345", nil];
NSMutableArray *descriptionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"description for ashu",@"description for non ashu",@"description for ashuabc",@"description for nopnashu",@"description for ashu12345", nil];

NSMutableArray *removedIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [firstArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *tempStr = [firstArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([tempStr rangeOfString:@"ashu"].location == NSNotFound) {
        [removedIndexArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    } else {
        [sortedArray addObject:tempStr];
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < [removedIndexArray count]; j++) {
    [descriptionArray removeObjectAtIndex:[[removedIndexArray objectAtIndex:j] integerValue]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",descriptionArray);
NSLog(@"Sorted array is :: %@",sortedArray);
```